# Adding in multiple layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers

I am trying to add in the following two layers into my OpenLayers 3 map. The issue i'm having is that whichever one is written in last is the only one that is showing. I imagine there is a way to combine some of this?

First Layer:

```
      var probableLoader = function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://PCNAME:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACENAME/ows?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=LAYER_probable&' +
        'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
        '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
  };

  var loadFeatures = function(response) {
    var features = probableSource.readFeatures(response);
    probableSource.addFeatures(features);
  };

  var probableSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: probableLoader,
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
      maxZoom: 19
    })),
  });

  var probable = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: probableSource,
    style: probableStyle,
    name: 'Probable'
  });
```

Second Layer:

```
      var committedLoader = function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://PCNAME:8080/geoserver/WORKSPACENAME/ows?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=LAYER_committed&' +
        'outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
        '&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
  };

  var loadFeatures = function(response) {
    var features = committedSource.readFeatures(response);
    committedSource.addFeatures(features);
  };

  var committedSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    loader: committedLoader,
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
      maxZoom: 19
    })),
  });

  var committed = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: committedSource,
    style: committedStyle,
    name: 'Committed'
  });
```

These are then combined into a map:

```
      var group = new ol.layer.Group({
   layers: [probable, committed],
   name: 'group'
  });

  var center = ol.proj.transform([-2.547855, 54.00366], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 5
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [background, group, vector],
    view: view
  });
```

Styles for the two layers:

```
      var committedFill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(69,89,3,0.4)'
  });

  var committedStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
  });

  var committedCircle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 4,
    fill: committedFill,
    stroke: committedStroke
  });

  var committedStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: committedFill,
    stroke: committedStroke,
    image: committedCircle
  });

  var probableFill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255,153,0,0.4)'
  });

  var probableStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
  });

  var probableCircle = new ol.style.Circle({
    radius: 4,
    fill: probableFill,
    stroke: probableStroke
  });

  var probableStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: probableFill,
    stroke: probableStroke,
    image: probableCircle
  });
```

Comment: I'm trying this out right now with your code, seems to be related to styles in my case. Have you tried commenting those out?

Comment: I have the styles separate to this, just didn't include in this example.

Comment: I know, have you tried commenting out `style: probableStyle` and `style: committedStyle` temporarily to see if that will load both of these? Or is it related to all 4 layers?

Comment: Do you mind posting your styles too? I rewrote my basic test styles, put them in arrays and now both feature layers show up with styles.

Comment: Thanks for looking everyone, styles have been added into the question now.

Comment: I tried the styles and they worked immediately, sorry I don't see what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks @chrki, well that answers that it's not an issue with the code. Which leads me to think it's something to do with the server not showing two views at once or some other script in my page messing it up. I'll test it out on a completely blank map.

Comment: Chat won't work, just one more thing: I remember I had to change "typename" in the server URL to "typeName" (note capitalization), or else I would get lots of errors in the console and an error message on the server side.

Comment: I changed that, didn't make any noticeable difference. However, after a closer look at the data, it's almost as though it is loading in both datasets but just under one layer and then giving it that one layer style...

Comment: @chrki fixed it! The solution was that "loadFeatures" repeated itself in both layers, so it was effectively calling both layers into the first one it read in.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is that in my code I had called in "loadFeatures" twice, once in each of the layers. Simply by renaming one of them it stopped calling both layers into the single one.